# Limit cycle in Matlab for 2nd order autonomous system

Tags: matlab, math, plot, cycle

I wish to create a limit cycle in Matlab. A limit cycle looks something like this:

[image]

I have no idea how to do it though, I've never done anything like this in Matlab.

The equations to describe the limit cycle are the following:

```
x_1d=x_2
x_2d=-x_1+x_2-2*(x_1+2*x_2)x_2^2
```

It is to be centered around the equilibrium which is (0,0)

Can any of you help me?

Comment: This looks like you want to plot an orbit, described by two coordinates as a function of a (time) parameter. You should provide the equations as a function of time

Comment: You mean like this instead?
    x_1d(t)=x_2(t)
    x_2d(t)=-x_1(t)+x_2(t)-2*(x_1(t)+2*x_2(t))x_2(t)^2


And yes, it should be centered around the equilibrium, (0,0)

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to plot the position of a particle overtime, something like a [streamline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines). In your given equation, you have (x_1, x_2, x1_d, x2_d). Can you label these variables?  Are x1_d and x2_d derivatives?

Comment: If you are interested in streamlines, you should check out the matlab [`steamline`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamline.html) function

Comment: x_1d and x_2d is the derivative of x_1 and x_2, respectively. It's the 2nd order non-linear differential system that governs the limit cycle.

Hm, I'm not quite sure how to use the streamline function to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the partial derivatives of your function to make a vector field, you can then use streamlines to visualize the cycle that you are describing.

For example, the function f = x^2+y^2

Gives me partial derivatives dx = 2x, dy=2y For the visualization, I sample from the partial derivatives over a grid.

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:1);
dx = 2*x;
dy = 2*y;
```

To visualize the vector field, I use `quiver`;

```
figure; 
quiver(x, y, dx, dy);
```

Using streamline, I can visualize the path a particle injected into the vector field would take. In my example, I inject the particle at (0.1, 0.1)

```
streamline(x,y, dx, dy, 0.1, 0.1);
```

This produces the following visualization

[image: Vector field streamline visualization example]

In your case, you can omit the quiver step to remove the hedgehog arrows at every grid point.

Here's another example that shows the particle converging to an orbit.

[image: Vector field visualization example]

**Edit: Your function specifically.**
So as knedlsepp points out, the function you are interested in is a bit ambiguously stated. In Matlab, `*` represents the matrix product while `.*` represents the element-wise multiplication between matrices. Similarly, '^2' represents `MM` for a matrix `M`, while `.^2` represents taking the element-wise power.

So,

```
[x_1,x_2] = meshgrid(-4:0.1:4,-4:0.1:4);
dx_1 = x_2;
dx_2 = -x_1+x_2-2*(x_1+2*x_2)*(x_2)^2;
figure; streamline(x_1,x_2, dx_1, dx_2, 0:0.1:4, 0:0.1:4);
```

Looks like

[image: Vector field visualization]

This function will not show convergence because it doesn't converge.

knedlsepp suggests that the function you are actually interested in is

```
dx_1 = -1 * x_2;
dx_2 = -1 * -x_1+x_2-2*(x_1+2*x_2).*(x_2).^2;
```

[His post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28995368/3303546) has a nice description of the rest.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried something like that before

    clc
    clear all

    [x_1,x_2] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1e2,0:0.1:1e2);
    dx_1 = x_2;
    dx_2 = -x_1+x_2-2*(x_1+2*x_2)*(x_2)^2;;

    figure; 
    streamline(x_1,x_2, dx_1, dx_2, 0, 0);

But when using (0,0) as the point it produces nothing, and when choosing another point I can get it to show the "orbit"

Comment: That makes sense because the vector field is 0 at (0,0) for your function. Basically equilibrium means the particle will not move, so injecting a particle at the equilibrium point will not show any streamlines. That's also why I choose (.1, .1) in my example rather than (0, 0). Choose another nearby point that makes a nice streamline to show the convergence to the equilibrium point. You could also insert multiple particles to show that many locations will converge to the equilibrium point.

Comment: In fact in your example diagram, it looks like 11 particles were injected along the line x=y. Try `x1_start = 0:4; x2_start=0:4; streamline(x_1, x_2, dx_1, dx_2, x1_start, x2_start)`

Comment: Arh of course! I've added multiple particles now. How did you make the last figure showing the orbit?
Didn't see your second response, I'll try that

Comment: Hm, I still can't get it to converge on the same "orbit"

Comment: Are the streamlines long enough to show your "orbit"? If they are simply too short, you can modify the stepsize and max_number_vertices options of the streamline function. You might want to increase the max_number_vertices.

Comment: I tried going pretty high
http://i60.tinypic.com/jii0k4.png

I've also tried even higher (-5e6:1000:5e6), but it still really didn't show the orbit

Comment: @knedlsepp In what way does he need to vectorize his code? He's not using any for loops.

Comment: There are two dots missing in `*(x_2)^2`. It should be `.*(x_2).^2` instead.

Comment: Argh yes. Now it works! Thank you so much to the both of you!

Answer (score 1):

This post shows the code to produce the integral lines of your vector field defined by:

```
dx/dt = y
dy/dt = -x+y-2*(x+2*y)*y^2.
```

It is important to properly vectorize this function. (i.e. Introducing dots at all the important places)

```
dxdt = @(x,y) y;
dydt = @(x,y) -x+y-2*(x+2*y).*y.^2;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-4,4,100));
[sx,sy] = meshgrid(linspace(-3,3,20));

streamline(stream2(X, Y, ...                % Points
                   dxdt(X,Y), dydt(X,Y),... % Derivatives
                   sx, sy));                % Starting points
axis equal tight
```

[image: integral lines]

To get a picture more similar to yours, change the grid size and starting points:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,100));
[sx,sy] = meshgrid(linspace(0,0.75,20),0.2);
```

[image: integral lines 2]